# Windows 8 desktop pc won't wake up / freezes

Tags: windows-8, freeze, sleep

There are a few questions about win 8 laptops having sleep problems. Mine is a desktop (so power options with batteries and such don't apply) and also my issue might be different.

My system is only about 6 months old. Pretty much every day now, whether I told the computer to go to sleep myself or just let it fall asleep from idling, I come back hours later and it's completely unresponsive. Sometimes the monitor is blank, but usually it's on, with a frozen image of the lock screen on it. It's weird because the screen will go blank when I put it to sleep, then suddenly come back on again when the system freezes up. I have to hard reboot to get it out of this state.

My motherboard is an [ASRock Z77](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157293), if that helps. Video card is a [GTX 570](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127682) - I tried looking for newer drivers but didn't find anything. I've kept up to date on Win 8 patches too.

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl-Alt-Delete on the frozen lock screen, and then typing your password? Maybe the display of the function is broken, but the option itself isn't. If I were you, for the time being, I'd try to reset all screensaver/lockscreen/login/power management/sleep settings to default. It might help you find the issue. Also, you might want to try a Windows repair from the advanced boot thingie in the General tab of the Modern UI PC settings. And the standard stuff for mysterious issues. Antivirus, defrag, etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, and uhm, perhaps it's one of your hardware pieces that doesn't wake up properly. Make sure everything inside the PC is plugged in fine and not too dusty. Might be surprised. The tech who made my previous PC had left a piece unplugged. You know how waking a PC up sometimes causes the fan to go vvvvvvvm, working hard? Is your fan sufficiently powered? Is every piece sufficiently powered? And if you think it might be a driver issue, then uninstall the drivers and reinstall them. Perhaps try a third party software like Driver Genius if you want.

Comment: @Ariane I assembled this machine myself. When it first started happening I opened it back up, checked all the connections, made sure fans were fine and video card was seated properly, etc. It's quite dust-free as well.

Comment: Running `powercfg -energy` from the command line might help diagnosing problems with the sleep state. The freeze thing in my experience is related to an hardware problem. The main suspect might be the power supply. This is unlikely if your computer is 6 months old, but if you can find another PSU, give it a try. Also, did you have another OS before Windows 8? Was the sleep thing working?